# Call C# class from Java class

Tags: java, c#, cross-platform

I have a java class and a c# class. I want to run that C# class from my java class.

However I don't want to pass anything from java code to c# and also don't want anything in return from C# code, I just want to run that C# code.

I want to do something like shown in below classes

**Java Class:**

```
public void static main(String[] args){

System.out.println("Running Java code ");

// here need to call C# class

}
}
```

I want this code to be executed from above java program

```
using System;
     class Program {
        Console.WriteLine("Running C# code ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the C# program `exe` file from java code.

first compile the C#.NET program to get the `Program.exe` file then run the same `Program.exe` from java code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Process process;
    process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ProjectsPath\\Program.exe").start();
}
```

Edit:

You can send the parameters to the exe file to be invoked by passing the arguments to the ProcessBuilder constructor as below:

Note : here im passing two argumenbts to Program.exe file Name and ID :

```
process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ProjectsPath\\Program.exe" , "Sudhakar","ID501").start();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to convert that C# code to an exe file because I don't have any idea of .Net framework

Comment: @ManojSingh : if you have visual studio IDE then build the project so that it creates the .exe file in the respective project folder.

Comment: Sudhakar I need one more help from you -- I want to some argument to that exe file can you help me how to do this

Comment: Thanks :) . Its wroking