# General Programming- Cross language compatible classes

Tags: java, c#

Can we create a class in say C# which can be used in other high-level languages like Java.?

To be more specific say, I have defined a function in c#. Now can I use the same function in other languages like Java without re-writing it and by using reference or anything else to the class in c# ?

The question here is not strictly limited to any particular language? Question here is that Can we create a class in one language which can be used in other language.

Comment: And what would be the benefit of that? In other words: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Other languages outside .NET may require different ways to communicate with C# class, such as P/Invoke to JNI/JNA. You can create class to a specific process, but you should know how to call the method inside it from specified language (i.e. Java).

Comment: please be more specific on what you mean by "use": compile/reference or sth.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call C# class from Java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353829/call-c-sharp-class-from-java-class)

Comment: Please see the updated question/post. @nozzleman

Comment: Your update has **invalidated** all the answers below

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use such a construct. A web service is language independent or you can call(a executable programme) with a cmd command.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we create a class in say C# which can be used in other high-level
>   languages like Java.?

**NOPE.**

Comment: @MickyD proove me wrong, before voting read my answer carefully. FYI a compiled program or web api is not a class

Comment: Just because you believe in _Flying Spaghetti Monsters_ or _fairies_, the [burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) does not rest on me

Comment: Flying Spaghetti Monsters and fairies all are real , dont you watch #GoT?

Comment: Haha sure do.  Some nice fire breathing flying monsters in today's episode :)

Comment: dont you think the solution there is more like calling another program rather than a single class?? and i bet it will work on windows only not on linux while java will rock

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> Can we create a class in say C# which can be used in other high-level languages like Java.?
>
> I have defined a function in c#. Now can I use the same function in other languages like Java without re-writing it

Yes it can be done.

You can generate Java proxy classes for invoking c# by using the tool [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/).

> bridge between Java and .NET (intraprocess, fast, object oriented, open-source)

This is what they have to say on the tool:

> Using reflection we grab public method signatures for core classes of .NET and Java and generated proxy classes for the other side.
>
> We have .NET version of JNI API.
>
> We use JNI to forward the call from .NET proxies to methods on real Java objects. (explanation)
>
> We use JNI to register .NET implementation of native methods of Java proxies to forward call to methods on real .NET objects  [More...](http://jni4net.com/)

Source and binaries are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jni4net/files/)

### But wait there's more!

Though not a requirement, you can use jni4net to call Java from .NET.

### See also

- [How calling from Java to .NET works in jni4net](http://zamboch.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/how-calling-from-java-to-net-works-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken: **No**

As some answers stated: For many languages there is a way of **invoking** methods/functionality of compiled compiler-output, but IMO the only szenarios I can think of it beeing useful is when it comes to legacy-software or not language-independent APIs (eg. not using rest). An Example could be calling a Method of a legacy-C#-`class` from a Java program for the sake of downward comnpatibility or because it was meant to work with .NET only. But you must be aware that there is no general approach of doing that which would work for any language-combination and IMO this is not **using** a `class`/method, its just invoking it.

When it comes to green-field projects, I would avoid using (to many) different languages (polyglot-programming). Maintainability suffers heaviliy because Developers need to know all used languages, use different IDEs etc. Also, debugging becomes a pain.

Using the same language for different parts of a system has the huge advantage of beeing able to use classes of some kind of shared libraries which are developed/tested independently.

However: if you are forced to use different languages for some reason, I would suggest to try and recreate the required shared functionality twice for each language (it sucks I know) and pass objects around by (de-)serializing them. This way, your projects remain testable and debuggable.